# Assigning functions to event handlers in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

I'm making a context menu component in Angular 2 where each menu item calls it's own function, which is defined by the model. I don't know how to embed the functions in the template though. An example of what I have is below. My specific problem is on this line:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="{{item.click}}">{{item.name}}</li>
```

When Adding the onclick handler. How can I do this?

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-context-menu',
  template: `<ul [hidden]="isHidden" #menu>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="{{item.click}}">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>`
})
export class ContextMenuComponent {

    @ViewChild('menu') menu: ElementRef;
    private items: Object[];
    private isHidden: boolean = true;

    constructor() {
      this.items =  [
        {name: 'One', click: () => alert('One')},
        {name: 'Two', click: () => alert('2')},
        {name: 'Three', click: () => alert('3')},
        {name: 'Four', click: () => alert('4')}
      ];
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try `(click)="item.click()"` in the template?

Comment: That works! If you make an answer out of it I can mark this as solved. Thanks.

Comment: You got it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in the template should be:

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="item.click()">{{item.name}}</li>
```